How to open an html file with Seleniumbase?
I am trying to do the following code but it retrieves me an error:
with SB() as sb:
sb.open(/path/file.html)
What is the proper way?
Thank you

Solution:
sb.load_html_file(html_file) 


To open an HTML file with SeleniumBase, you need to use the open method of the SeleniumBase instance. However, you need to ensure that you pass the file path as a string, and it's a relative or absolute path to the HTML file. Here's the correct way to do it:
    from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
def test_open_html_file(self):
    with self.create_selenium() as sb:
        sb.open("/path/to/your/file.html")

Make sure to replace "/path/to/your/file.html" with the actual path to your HTML file. Also, remember that SeleniumBase is typically used for web automation testing, so opening an HTML file directly might not be a common use case. Usually, you'd interact with web pages accessed through URLs.
